# Border/frame for special text in latex

Tags: graphics, framed, text-decorations

I'm writing about hash strings like this: 
"1DGooBsCL8eBHRq4UHPwiYbvu2Weiuw837" etc.

I would like to do some border box or decorations for hash strings. Is it possible in latex?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Yes, this is certainly possible - there are a variety of different packages that can help: `listings`, and `tcolorbox` for example

Comment: Some like  `\fbox{hash string}` or `\fcolorbox{red}{cyan}{hash string}`?

Comment: @TeXnician Done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, in many ways. Only to show some of them:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{soul}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{enhanced,colframe=red!50,colback=yellow!25,
nobeforeafter,shrink tight,left skip=1ex, right skip=1ex, extrude by=1.5mm}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.4, .6, .3}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{framed}
% \usepackage{xcolor} % loaded already by other packages
% \usepackage{tikz} % loaded already by other packages
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\linespread{2}  

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\fbox{hash string}  

\raisebox{-1ex}{\shadowsize3pt\shadowbox{hash string}}  

\fcolorbox{red}{cyan!20}{hash string} % need xcolor

\ovalbox{hash string}  

\Ovalbox{hash string}  

\doublebox{hash string}  

\tcbox{hash string}

\tcbox[drop fuzzy shadow]{hash string} 

\hl{hash string}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, pattern=grid, pattern color=blue!20 ] (m) {hash string};
\draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, preaction={fill,red!10} ] (m) {hash string};
\draw[dotted] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```